# Событие закрытия окна ActionScript

Tags: события, flash, actionscript

Как выполнить код перед закрытием приложения?
Пробовал:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING, onClosing);

function onClosing(e:Event):void
{
   e.preventDefault();
   trace('работает!');
}
```

Выдает ошибки:

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property NativeWindow through a reference with static typeflash.display:Stage.
1119: Access of possibly undefined property CLOSING through a reference with static type Class.
```

В чем дело понять не могу.
ActionScript 3, Flash Player 11.2.

Comment: nativeWindow

с маленькой

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: у вас AIR приложение ? 
Проверили NativeWindow.isSupported ?
Оно работает только на десктоп AIR приложениях.

http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html

Comment: Нет, у меня не AIR приложение. Есть ли способы для Flash Player 11.2?

Comment: Способы чего? Перехватить событие закрытия окна браузера? Нет.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В настройках публикации поменял Flash Player 11.2 на AIR 2.5.
Во Flash всё нормально работает, а в браузере на сервере нет.
И похоже не будет.

Comment: Класс NativeWindow в вебплеере недоступен.